# unsplash-wallpaper random in Windows Tasks, but not in background. How to?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, desktop-customization, windows-task-scheduler

I need to start this:

`unsplash-wallpaper random`

every hour on my Windows Desktop, but without Windows Command Prompt on Desktop every time.

How to start it in background?

**UPDATE**:

I tried to uncheck the radio button "Run wheter user is connected" and nothign happens. Tried also with SYSTEM and wallpaper doesn't change.

Comment: I tried to uncheck the radio button "Run wheter user is connected" and nothign happens. Tried also with SYSTEM and wallpaper doesn't change.

Comment: Please edit your question and include this as it's important information :)

Comment: Set up a [Scheduled Task](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard)

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks, but the problem isn't how to start Tasks Manager in Windows.

Comment: Then clearly you question is not clear ;) Please include screenshots of your Schedule settings. Upload your image to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get a link you can share. [Edit] your question to include this link and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem isn't the task scheduler, but rather the way you call the program. Let me guess: You are using the awesome [unsplash-wallpaper](https://github.com/cuth/unsplash-wallpaper) program from cuth.

So use the *.cmd in your task (%appdata%\npm\unsplash-wallpaper.cmd):

[image: Task settings]

This will show a cmd window every time the task starts. But you can wrap it into a vb-script.